# What's the word or expression when you do something that the outcome is already decided?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have to submit some paperwork for the approval of an activity. However, I have already got approval, the paperwork is only necessary to submit the specifics (the date, people involved, and other details which have already been approved) for sign-off.

What is the word (or expression, but preferably a single-word) to describe this kind of action?

Examples:

> I already have approval, so submitting this paperwork is a ____ act.
>
> I already have approval, so the paperwork is just ____.

It's not *"futile"* as it's still necessary, I'm not *"going through the motions"* as I really mean it and my heart is in it, so how can I describe this paperwork?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

> ***just a formality***

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formality):

> ***formality*** 3. An established form, rule, or custom, especially one followed merely for the sake of procedure or decorum.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it - it was so frustrating not being able to think of this.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [**pro forma**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_forma), "for the form". Wiki says:

> The term pro forma (Latin for "as a matter of form" or "for the sake of form") is most often used to describe a practice or document that is provided as a courtesy and/or satisfies minimum requirements, conforms to a norm or doctrine, tends to be performed perfunctorily and/or is considered a formality.

Answer (score 0):

Jim's answer is probably the phrase your looking for, however you could also use *predetermined*.